# how to disable welcome message in minicom

Tags: 12.10

I'v receive welcome message as below and i want to remove that when i start minicom, please help.

```
Welcome to minicom 2.5

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Dec  7 2011, 12:04:29.
Port /dev/ttyUSB0
Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Turning off modem initialization strings**
>
> Besides serial port settings (the most common being 115200,N,8,1), it is often necessary to turn off the modem initialization strings for minicom. By default, minicom is intended to create a serial connection over a modem. But when using minicom with a kernel serial console, if modem initialization strings are used, this may confuse the kernel console initialization routines. (Which can result in gibberish being output on the serial line). To disable the modem initialization strings, set the variables 'minit', 'mreset', and 'mhangup' to be emtpy. You can do this with the following lines in a minicom config file:

```
pu minit
pu mreset
pu mhangup
```

[Source](http://elinux.org/Minicom).

Config file: `/etc/minicom/minirc.<connection>`.